# Go To Full Site Magento Link To Change Themes

Tags: magento

I have used the built-in iphone theme in Magento 1.7.0.2 to create a mobile site, the problem that I am having is creating a link so that the user has the option to go back to the full site, is there a way to create link to change the theme in Magento or create a link that makes Magento see the mobile as a normal web browser?

I have looked at a number of things such as trying to make the mobile appear to have a different user agent once the link is clicked but I have had no look

Thanks in advance

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create 2 store views: one for the mobile version and second for full version. 
Ex: http://example.com/ and http://example.com/m/

You have patterns for mobile user agents, so you can check if user came with mobile deviсe — redirect him to the mobile store (http://example.com/m/) and just add link to the main store: http://example.com/

One more solution is to use one and the same URI and just add store code to the address:
`http://example.com/?___store=mobile` and `http://example.com/?___store=full`.

Comment: parser does not want to show coorect value, it should be ?___store=

Comment: @Daniel : Is there any workaround in case where my mobile theme and web theme use the same url. http://example.com
I tried to dynamically switch the themes and i was able switch the theme from web to mobile but not from mobile to web.